# Localization IOS default Language

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, localization

I have build an iphone app and I started with Dutch texts in the app. I would like to expand it to other countries so I Localized the app and added English.

So I have now to localization folders en.lproj and nl.lproj.

When I install the app on the iphone and set the language to Dutch I get the Dutch language in the App. When I switch to English I get this. But when I switch to German I get the Dutch language. I would like to have default the English language when the is no localization folder for it.

How do I do this?

Comment: It should be English by default... if you are not explicitly changing the language...

Answer (score 3):

*A little late to the party, but just recently run into this issue and somebody helped me, so here is the magic:*

Suppose your app supports English and Spanish.

If the list of languages in the Settings app is Portuguese, Spanish, English then Spanish will be shown to the user. If the list has been Portuguese, English, Spanish then English would be shown to the user.

In short, the language are loaded in order, so if you want English to be loaded when German (or any other missing language) is set, your settings screen should read:

German | English | Dutch | everything else

But you don't know how your users has the languages set and English might be at the bottom. So far, the best <strike>solution</strike> workaround I found was to manually change the Locale order on startup so English is always second, and therefore, default.

Comment: users can not reorder the languages on iOS -- thats osx 10.8 and below

Comment: Actually, say you choose German as your device language. Then change it to Italian and after that to Spanish. The languages list in your Settings Page will be: Spanish|Italian|German|TheRest. So, in that case, your app will try to load your Spanish localizable.strings. If not found, the Italian one, and then the German one, and so on. At least this is the behaviour I found over the last couple days.

Comment: @andres.cianio At first, I thought I configure default language setting incorrectly somewhere. But this is not a bug, it's a feature! Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your Info.plist you have to set the `Localization native development region` to `English` (`en`) and it should work fine.

Comment: Yeah, That's what I read everywhere but it doesn't? Can it be that something in my plist is messed up?